# Вывести массив слотов json

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Добрый день проблема следующая, хочу вывести на Ajax расписание автомоек, есть php код который делает слоты (времени когда автомойка свободна), задача вывеси массив с слотами времени

```
        $json = array();

        for ($i = strtotime($slot_start); $i <= strtotime($slot_end); $i = $i + $slot_step * 60) {
            $json = array(
                'time'               => date("H:i", $i),
                'booked'             => false,
            );  
         }
```

При обращении к коду выводиться слот 11:45 а не все возможные слоты (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$slots = [];
for ($i = strtotime($slot_start); $i <= strtotime($slot_end); $i = $i + $slot_step * 60) {
  $slots[] = ['time'=> date("H:i", $i),'booked'=> false];  
}
echo json_encode ($slots);
```